# servlet mysql Runtime Exception

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, 
>   which is 0)

For the following code, what kind of parameter change is required to make the code run?

```
package com.chen.util;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SqlHelper {
    private static Connection conn = null;
    private static PreparedStatement ps = null;
    private static ResultSet rs = null;

    private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdata";
    private static String username1 = "root";
    private static String password1 = "root";

    static {
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }
    }


    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username1, password1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }



        public static void executeUpdate(String sql, String[] parameters) {

        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            if (parameters != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
                    ps.setString(i+1 , parameters[i]);
                }
            }

            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            close(rs,ps,conn);
        }
    }

    public static ResultSet executeQuery(String sql,String[]parameters){
        try{
            conn=getConnection();
            ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            if(parameters!=null&&!parameters.equals("")){
                for(int i=0;i<parameters.length;i++){
                    ps.setString(i+1,parameters[i]);
                }
            }
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            //close(rs,ps,conn);
        }
        return rs;
    }

        public static void close(ResultSet rs, PreparedStatement ps, Connection    conn) {
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            rs = null;
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ps = null;
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            conn = null;
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConn() {
        return conn;
    }

    public static PreparedStatement getPs() {
        return ps;
    }

    public static ResultSet getRs() {
        return rs;
    }
}
```

Below is the error stack:

```
//java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1062)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:904)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3797)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3779)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:4600)
    at com.chen.util.SqlHelper.executeQuery(SqlHelper.java:100)
    at com.chen.services.UserService.checkUser(UserService.java:22)
    at com.chen.controller.ControllerServlet.doGet(ControllerServlet.java:33)
    at 

package com.chen.services;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.chen.domain.User;
import com.chen.util.SqlHelper;

public class UserService {

// 用checkUser()来判断用户是否存在

public boolean checkUser(User user) {
    boolean b = false;
    // 使用SqlHelper来完成查询任务
    String sql = "select * from user where username=? and password=?";
    String parameters[] = { user.getUsername(), user.getPassowrd() };
    ResultSet rs = SqlHelper.executeQuery("sql", parameters);
    // 根据rs来判断该用户是否存在
    try {
        if (rs.next()) {
            b = true;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        SqlHelper.close(rs, SqlHelper.getPs(), SqlHelper.getConn());
    }
    return b;
}

public ArrayList getUserByPage(int pageNow, int pageSize) {
    ArrayList<User> arr = new ArrayList<User>();
    // 查询sql
    //String sql = "select * from user where id>3 order by id limit 20";
    String sql="select sql_calc_found_rows * from user limit 0,10";
    ResultSet rs = SqlHelper.executeQuery(sql, null);
    // 二次封装 把 ResultSet -->User对象-->Arraylist(集合)
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            User u = new User();
            try {
                u.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                u.setUsername(rs.getString(2));
                u.setPassowrd(rs.getString(3));
                // 一定记住 u-->ArrayList
                arr.add(u);
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        SqlHelper.close(rs, SqlHelper.getPs(), SqlHelper.getConn());
    }
    return arr;
}

public int getPageCount(int pageSize) {
    String sql = "select * from user";
    int rowCount = 0;
    ResultSet rs = SqlHelper.executeQuery(sql, null);
    try {
        rs.next();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        rowCount = rs.getInt(1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        SqlHelper.close(rs, SqlHelper.getPs(), SqlHelper.getConn());
    }
    return (rowCount - 1) / pageSize + 1;
}
//删除用户
public boolean deleUser(String id){
    boolean b=true;
    String sql="delete from user where id=?";
    String parameters[]={id};;
    try {
        SqlHelper.executeUpdate(sql, parameters);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        b=false;
    }
    return b;
}
//用过id获取用户数据
public User getUserById(String id){
    User user=new User();
    String sql="select * from user where id= ?";
    String parameters[]={id};
    ResultSet rs=SqlHelper.executeQuery(sql, parameters);
    try {
        if(rs.next()){
            user.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            user.setUsername(rs.getString(2));
            user.setPassowrd(rs.getString(3));

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        SqlHelper.close(rs, SqlHelper.getPs(), SqlHelper.getConn());
    }
    return user;
}
//修改用户
public boolean updateUser(User user){
    boolean b=true;
    String sql="update user set username=?,password=? where id=?";
    String parameters[]={user.getUsername(),user.getPassowrd(),user.getId()+""};
    try {
        SqlHelper.executeUpdate(sql, parameters);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        b=false;
    }
    return b;
}
```

}

Comment: you need to show the code that calls `executeQuery` (or `executeUpdate`, whichever is throwing this exception). What are the parameters that are passed in?
The number of "?" signs in the sql query must be the same as the size of the parameters array. The error you are getting looks like you are passing in sql string without any "?", and a parametes array of size 1. Also note that this check in `executeUpdate` is always true: `!parameters.equals("")`. Perhaps, you meant to do something else there?

Comment: Hi Dima i am checking with the code ill get bach soon and thanks for your response.

Comment: hi Dima could you check with my query part

Comment: insufficient information. Can you please provide more information for better understanding

Comment: still i cant solve the issues, please any one could help?

Comment: check the size of parameters satisfy the number query parameters used in the prepared statements

Comment: i have posted the code,could you please explain me in which part of code .

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
ResultSet rs = SqlHelper.executeQuery("sql", parameters);
```

With:

```
ResultSet rs = SqlHelper.executeQuery(sql, parameters);
```

Comment: its not working, evern after i replace "sql".. need help please

Comment: yes the same exception

Comment: yes recco, do i need to change all "sql" to sql?

Comment: Yes,of course."sql" mean new String("sql") insead of your sql statement above

Comment: ok, will try and get back recco,

Comment: hi recco, how to implement

Comment: how to implement "you need to show the code that calls executeQuery (or executeUpdate, whichever is throwing this exception). What are the parameters that are passed in? The number of "?" signs in the sql query must be the same as the size of the parameters array. The error you are getting looks like you are passing in sql string without any "?", and a parametes array of size 1. Also note that this check in executeUpdate is always true: !parameters.equals(""). Perhaps, you meant to do something else there? "

Comment: you can debug to figure out the problem of your code is.

Comment: Hi Recco, your method helped me to fix my issues, thanks a million.